# Group by same date in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, group-by

I have a userRegister table with following fields:

```
    **userRegister table:**

    id | name | created            | login               | logout | userId
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |test | 2018-02-19 11:34:00  | 2018-02-19 11:34:00 | NULL  |  1
2  |test | 2018-02-21 14:01:42 | 2018-02-21 14:01:42 | NULL   |  1
3  |test | 2018-02-21 15:24:05 | 2018-02-21 15:24:05 | NULL   |  1
4  |test | 2018-02-22 16:46:15 | 2018-02-22 16:46:15 | NULL   |  1
5  |test2 | 2018-02-27 09:51:19 | 2018-02-27 09:51:19 | NULL  |  2
6  |test2 | 2018-02-28 11:59:24 | 2018-02-28 11:59:24 | NULL  |  2
7  |test  |2018-03-01 10:37:59 | 2018-03-01 10:37:59 | NULL   |  1
8  |test  |2018-03-01 10:39:52 | 2018-03-01 10:39:52 | NULL   |  1
9  |test  |2018-03-01 10:41:49 | 2018-03-01 10:41:49 | NULL   |  1
10  |test  |2018-03-01 15:34:52 | 2018-03-01 15:34:52 | NULL  |  1
```

Here i need to check if user has login on same day multiple time without logging out than
i need to update `logout` field with previous login time

how write a query that group the user by created date for multiple login without logging out

Code i tried:

```
db.query("select * from userRegister where logout is NULL limit 10", function (err, user) {
        if (!_.size(user)){
            console.log([])
        }
        else{
            var result=_.chain(user).groupBy("created").map(function(v, i) {
                return {
                        created: i,
                        login: _.map(v, 'login'),
                        userId: _.map(v, 'userId')
                    }
            }).value()
        }
})
```

output:

```
[ { created: '2018-02-19 11:34:00',
    login: [ '2018-02-19 11:34:00' ],
    userId: [ '1' ] },
  { created: '2018-02-21 14:01:42',
    login: [ '2018-02-21 14:01:42' ],
    userId: [ '1' ] },
  { created: '2018-02-21 15:24:05',
    login: [ '2018-02-21 15:24:05' ],
    userId: [ '1' ] },
  { created: '2018-02-22 16:46:15',
    login: [ '2018-02-22 16:46:15' ],
    userId: [ '1' ] },
  { created: '2018-02-27 09:51:19',
    login: [ '2018-02-27 09:51:19' ],
    userId: [ '2' ] },
  { created: '2018-02-28 11:59:24',
    login: [ '2018-02-28 11:59:24' ],
    userId: [ '2' ] },
  { created: '2018-03-01 10:37:59',
    login: [ '2018-03-01 10:37:59' ],
    userId: [ '1' ] },
  { created: '2018-03-01 10:39:52',
    login: [ '2018-03-01 10:39:52' ],
    userId: [ '1' ] },
  { created: '2018-03-01 10:41:49',
    login: [ '2018-03-01 10:41:49' ],
    userId: [ '1' ] },
  { created: '2018-03-01 15:34:52',
    login: [ '2018-03-01 15:34:52' ],
    userId: [ '1' ] } ]
```

Output should be group by created date (same date) or is there any other way to do it ? Please suggest

Comment: Why would you group by date when there is only 1 record per user?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden there are many data i just added 1 data above

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Edit your question and add sample data of a record where a user didn't log out and where  they did logout. Is the logout column null? Has the same time as login? Lookup the MySQL date functions to see how you can get just the date part of a date-time value.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I will add the code i tried

Comment: With the structure in your question, how can there be multiple login/logout rows per user?

Comment: @SloanThrasher I have updated my question with  all the records.Please check

Comment: See @cdaiga answer below, that should give you the result you're looking for. You should tag the question with the scripting language and/or library you are using.

Comment: I added the number of logins without logouts to cdaiga's SQLfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e286a/10/0).

Comment: @SloanThrasher  I have updated my code and output here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758446/update-login-date-with-logout-date-using-mysql-and-nodejs

Comment: @SloanThrasher Checked cdaiga and your SQLfiddle (empty) but it will group the data by date but i wanted the data in other way. Mentioned it in the link given above

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, userId, DATE(login) loginDate
FROM userRegister 
WHERE logout IS NULL
GROUP BY name, userId, DATE(login)
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

See a [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e286a/2).

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like that :
EDIT: My Bad i have forgotten the group by

```
select userId, name, created, date(login) as date_login, count(*) as nb_login
from YourTable
WHERE logout IS NULL
GROUP BY userId, date_login
HAVING nb_login > 1
```

EDIT with update on logout field

```
SET @last_login:=NULL;

UPDATE userRegister r JOIN (
SELECT name, userId, login, if(logout is NULL, @last_login, logout) as logout
, @last_login :=login as dummy
FROM userRegister 
ORDER BY userId, login desc) d USING(userId, login) SET r.logout = d.logout;
```

Comment: This return one value @A.colonna

Comment: I have edited and fix my code. Sorry i have forgotten one line.

Comment: Thanks, its give count of Login in particular date.

Comment: I need to update the logout field with next login time for that, first i will get all data with logout IS NULL and groupby login later i am struck like how to do it

Comment: That’s a different question.

Comment: You want to update all the fields with logout NULl ?

Comment: yes, need to update logout filed to its next login value