# Update login date with logout date using mysql and nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a userregister table. First i need to check for same day if there is multiple login by same catId on same day.Than i need to update the logout field with next login field value.

for now i have grouped data based on common login date. but i need to update logout field with belogns to same catId and same day. I am not getting how to do it

Please suggest how to do it ?

USER REGISTER table:

```
    id | name | created            | login               | logout | userId | catId
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |test | 2018-02-19 11:34:00  | 2018-02-19 11:34:00    | NULL   |  1     |  11
2  |test | 2018-02-21 14:01:42 | 2018-02-21 14:01:42     | NULL   |  1     |  11
3  |test | 2018-02-21 15:24:05 | 2018-02-21 15:24:05     | NULL   |  1     |  12
4  |test | 2018-02-22 16:46:15 | 2018-02-22 16:46:15     | NULL   |  1     |  11
5  |test2 | 2018-02-27 09:51:19 | 2018-02-27 09:51:19    | NULL   |  2     |  11
6  |test2 | 2018-02-28 11:59:24 | 2018-02-28 11:59:24    | NULL   |  2     |  13
7  |test  |2018-03-01 10:37:59 | 2018-03-01 10:37:59     | NULL   |  1     |  12
8  |test  |2018-03-01 10:39:52 | 2018-03-01 10:39:52     | NULL   |  1     |  12
9  |test  |2018-03-01 10:41:49 | 2018-03-01 10:41:49     | NULL   |  1     |  13
10  |test  |2018-03-01 15:34:52 | 2018-03-01 15:34:52    | NULL   |  1     |  13
```

Code tried:

```
db.query("select *, date(login) as login_date from userRegister where logout is NULL limit 10", function (err, user) {
        if (!_.size(user)){
            console.log([])
        }
        else{
            var userArr =_.groupBy(user,'login_date')
            console.log(userArr)  //array grouped by date
        }
})
```

Output:

```
  { '2018-02-19': 
       [ RowData {
           created: '2018-02-19 11:34:00',
           login:  '2018-02-19 11:34:00' ,
           userId:  '1',
           catId: '11',
           login_date: '2018-02-19'  } ],
        '2018-02-21': 
       [ RowData { 
            created: '2018-02-21 14:01:42',
            login:   '2018-02-21 14:01:42',
            userId: '1',
            catId: '11',
           login_date: '2018-02-21'  },
         RowData { 
            created: '2018-02-21 15:24:05',
            login:   '2018-02-21 15:24:05',
            userId: '1',
            catId: '12',
           login_date: '2018-02-21'  } ],
        '2018-02-22': 
       [ RowData {
           created: '2018-02-22 16:46:15',
           login: '2018-02-22 16:46:15',
           userId: '1',
           catId: '11',
           login_date: '2018-02-22' }],
        '2018-02-27':
        [RowData {
           created: '2018-02-27 09:51:19',
           login: '2018-02-27 09:51:19',
           userId: '2',
           catId: '11',
           login_date: '2018-02-27' }],
        '2018-02-28':
        [RowData {
           created: '2018-02-28 11:59:24',
           login: '2018-02-28 11:59:24',
           userId: '2',
           catId: '13',
           login_date: '2018-02-28' }],
        '2018-03-01':
        [RowData {
           created: '2018-03-01 10:37:59',
           login: '2018-03-01 10:37:59',
           userId: '1',
           catId: '12',
           login_date: '2018-03-01'  },
        RowData {
           created: '2018-03-01 10:39:52',
           login: '2018-03-01 10:39:52',
           userId: '1',
           catId: '12',
           login_date: '2018-03-01'  },
        RowData {
           created: '2018-03-01 10:41:49',
           login: '2018-03-01 10:41:49',
           userId: '1',
           catId: '13',
           login_date: '2018-03-01'  },
        RowData {
           created: '2018-03-01 15:34:52',
           login: '2018-03-01 15:34:52',
           userId: '1',
           catId: '13',
           login_date: '2018-03-01' }],
        }
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
 var byCatId = _.groupBy(user, 'catId');


    var grouppedArray = _.map(byCatId, function(array) {
                                        return _.groupBy(array, 'login_date')
                                    });

    for(var k=0;k<grouppedArray[i][j].length;k++){
        if(grouppedArray[i][j][k+1]){
var updatedLogOut = moment(grouppedArray[i][j][k+1].login).subtract(1, 'minutes').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
            db.query('update userRegister set  logout= ? where userId = ? and catId = ?', [updatedLogOut, 1, grouppedArray[i][j][k].userId, grouppedArray[i][j][k].catId], function (err, updatedLogout) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Is this coding is correct ? i mean is it bad way of doing or any other good method or alternative for this exist. Please help

In this i am getting error `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` near 'INTERVAL 1 Minute'. what is that i am missing here ? 
I found an alternative for this i.e moment (module)

Comment: Is there  any javascript /Nodejs way to do it. Kindly suggest

Comment: I found alternative for SUBDATE(), i.e moment .

Answer (score 1):

As i said in your post yesterday you can do this in full mysql with some variables:

```
SET @last_login:=NULL;
SET @last_user:=NULL; 
SET @last_cat:=NULL; 

UPDATE userRegister r JOIN (
SELECT name, userId, catId,  login,
if((logout is NULL) AND (@last_user=userId) AND (@last_cat=catId), @last_login, logout) as logout
, @last_login :=login as dummy_log
, @last_user:=userId as dummy_user
, @last_cat:=catId as dummy_cat
FROM userRegister 
ORDER BY userId, catId, login desc) d USING(userId, catId, login) SET r.logout = d.logout;
```

Comment: @A. Colonna I  tried this but i got syntax error, mysql version is 5.Is it because mysql     wont support these not sure

Comment: @A.Colonna query executed with no error,but issue is it updated the logout with login value of same field. its should be day1: logout should be updated with day2: login. But here its updating day1:logout with day1 login

Comment: i don't understand because i try it on sqlfiddle and it works: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e4c71/1/3

Comment: @A.Colonna may be because i am using mysql it might not supporting

Comment: please give me the result you have in your mysql version in sqlfiddle you can change the mysql version

Comment: @A.Colonna Sorry, but i dont know how to set mysql version in sqlfiddle. But i will search and try to create one. currently due to timeline i need to complete this task asap. I will update my code above which is working but stuck in one point. Thanks a ton for your help